# Need help replacing value in one cell in an existing Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cell

I am pulling data from the SEC Edgar site. Rows include Q1 Q2 Q3 and FY fiscal periods.  I want to subtract the values of the preceding three quarters from the FY value.

Here is the code:

```
def BackOutFiscalYears ( df):
    if df.empty:
        return df
    Length = len(df)
    if Length < 4:
        return df
    ndx = Length - 1
    while ndx >=4:
        if df.iloc[ndx]['fp'] == 'FY':
            QtrValue = df.iloc[ndx]['val'] - (df.iloc[ndx-1]['val'] + df.iloc[ndx-2]['val']  + df.iloc[ndx-3]['val'])
            QtrValue = int(QtrValue)
            # print ( f'QtrValue {QtrValue}')
            
            # the next line is what I want (it looks logical) but it throws a warning and does not replace the cell 
            # df.iloc[ndx]['val'] = QtrValue
            
            # tried these things but they all blow up
            # df.at[ndx,'val'] = QtrValue
            # df.loc[ndx]['val'] = QtrValue
            # df.loc[df.loc[ndx,'val']] = QtrValue
            
            # this does weird stuff. 
            # converts everything to floats. Even though QtrValue is a int.
            # add rows with correct values in 'val' column, all other columns NaN
            df.loc[ndx,'val'] = QtrValue
            
        ndx -= 1
    return df
```

Here is the dataframe before and after the function is called:

```
          start         end          val                  accn    fy  fp  form       filed     frame
156  2020-01-01  2020-03-31  17571000000  0001558370-21-004922  2021  Q1  10-Q  2021-04-27  CY2020Q1
160  2020-04-01  2020-06-30  18123000000  0001558370-21-009351  2021  Q2  10-Q  2021-07-27  CY2020Q2
164  2020-07-01  2020-09-30  17560000000  0001558370-21-014734  2021  Q3  10-Q  2021-11-05  CY2020Q3
167  2020-01-01  2020-12-31  55179000000  0001558370-23-002376  2022  FY  10-K  2023-02-28    CY2020
169  2021-01-01  2021-03-31  13187000000  0001558370-22-005983  2022  Q1  10-Q  2022-04-26  CY2021Q1
173  2021-04-01  2021-06-30  14218000000  0001558370-22-010985  2022  Q2  10-Q  2022-07-25  CY2021Q2
177  2021-07-01  2021-09-30  13251000000  0001558370-22-015322  2022  Q3  10-Q  2022-10-25  CY2021Q3
179  2021-01-01  2021-12-31  57350000000  0001558370-23-002376  2022  FY  10-K  2023-02-28    CY2021
181  2022-01-01  2022-03-31  14197000000  0001558370-23-006656  2023  Q1  10-Q  2023-04-25  CY2022Q1
185  2022-04-01  2022-06-30  15535000000  0000051143-23-000021  2023  Q2  10-Q  2023-07-25  CY2022Q2
189  2022-07-01  2022-09-30  14107000000  0000051143-23-000032  2023  Q3  10-Q  2023-10-31  CY2022Q3
190  2022-01-01  2022-12-31  60530000000  0001558370-23-002376  2022  FY  10-K  2023-02-28    CY2022
191  2023-01-01  2023-03-31  14252000000  0001558370-23-006656  2023  Q1  10-Q  2023-04-25  CY2023Q1
193  2023-04-01  2023-06-30  15475000000  0000051143-23-000021  2023  Q2  10-Q  2023-07-25  CY2023Q2
195  2023-07-01  2023-09-30  14752000000  0000051143-23-000032  2023  Q3  10-Q  2023-10-31  CY2023Q3
          start         end           val                  accn      fy   fp  form       filed     frame
181  2022-01-01  2022-03-31  1.419700e+10  0001558370-23-006656  2023.0   Q1  10-Q  2023-04-25  CY2022Q1
185  2022-04-01  2022-06-30  1.553500e+10  0000051143-23-000021  2023.0   Q2  10-Q  2023-07-25  CY2022Q2
189  2022-07-01  2022-09-30  1.410700e+10  0000051143-23-000032  2023.0   Q3  10-Q  2023-10-31  CY2022Q3
190  2022-01-01  2022-12-31  6.053000e+10  0001558370-23-002376  2022.0   FY  10-K  2023-02-28    CY2022
191  2023-01-01  2023-03-31  1.425200e+10  0001558370-23-006656  2023.0   Q1  10-Q  2023-04-25  CY2023Q1
193  2023-04-01  2023-06-30  1.547500e+10  0000051143-23-000021  2023.0   Q2  10-Q  2023-07-25  CY2023Q2
195  2023-07-01  2023-09-30  1.475200e+10  0000051143-23-000032  2023.0   Q3  10-Q  2023-10-31  CY2023Q3
55          NaN         NaN  1.669400e+10                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
51          NaN         NaN  1.925000e+09                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
47          NaN         NaN  2.343000e+09                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
39          NaN         NaN  2.254200e+10                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
35          NaN         NaN  2.177100e+10                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
27          NaN         NaN  2.411300e+10                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
23          NaN         NaN  3.341400e+10                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
19          NaN         NaN  2.767100e+10                   NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN         NaN       NaN
```

I know this question has been asked and answered many times, and I have tried several of the suggested solutions to no avail.

I tried this:
`df.iloc[ndx]['val'] = QtrValue`

But the value was not updated and I got a warning.

After several trying several from StackOverflow and elsewhere I tried:
`df.loc[ndx,'val'] = QtrValue`

But strange rows are added and it isn't right

Thank you very much.  Tom

Comment: I don't really understand your goal (but I'm also not much into finance): What are "the values of the preceding three quarters"? and what is the value you want to get? (described in words maybe)

Comment: its difficult to guess what you want with a function that didn't really work on input dataframe. Why don't you try posting expected output dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to substract the sum of all quarterly values from FY value. If thats right, you can try the below:

```
df['year']=df['frame'].str.extract('(\d+)')  #Extracts year from frame column
df['value_sum']=df.groupby(['year'])['val'].transform("sum") # sums val/value col by year
df['year_sub_quarter']=np.where(df['fp']=='FY',df['val']-(df['value_sum']-df['val']),np.nan)                                            #calculates FY val - sum of quarterly val
print(df['year_sub_quarter'])
```

Comment: Your answer completely missed the point.  I have no problem calculating the new value (QtrValue).  I do not want to print the value, I want to replace the value in the row (indicated by ndx) with QtrValue.  I am trying to do that in the third to last row of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ChatGPT for providing the following code which solves my problem.  Two changes were made: 1) use a copy of the data frame and 2) use iloc instead of loc.

```
def BackOutFiscalYears(df):
if df.empty:
    return df.copy()
Length = len(df)
if Length < 4:
    return df.copy()

# Create a copy of the DataFrame to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning
df_copy = df.copy()

ndx = Length - 1
while ndx >= 3:
    if 'fp' in df_copy.columns and df_copy.iloc[ndx]['fp'] == 'FY':
        QtrValue = df_copy.iloc[ndx]['val'] - (df_copy.iloc[ndx-1]['val'] + df_copy.iloc[ndx-2]['val'] + df_copy.iloc[ndx-3]['val'])
        QtrValue = int(QtrValue)
        df_copy.iloc[ndx, df_copy.columns.get_loc('val')] = QtrValue
    ndx -= 1
return df_copy
```

Comment: Thanks to all who tried to understand my confusing initial post!